# Cannot build Android in codename one

Tags: android, codenameone

I have found the following error when trying to build Android.
iOS debug and release are both ok.

```
All input files are considered out-of-date for incremental task ':compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
Compiling with source level 1.7 and target level 1.7.
:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac - is not incremental (e.g. outputs have changed, no previous execution, etc.).
file or directory '/tmp/build6717517675623000166xxx/MainUI/src/release/java', not found
Compiling with JDK Java compiler API.
/tmp/build6717517675623000166xxx/MainUI/src/main/java/com/codename1/social/GoogleImpl.java:40: error: package com.google.android.gms.auth.api does not exist
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth;
                                      ^
/tmp/build6717517675623000166xxx/MainUI/src/main/java/com/codename1/social/GoogleImpl.java:41: error: package com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin does not exist
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;
                                             ^
/tmp/build6717517675623000166xxx/MainUI/src/main/java/com/codename1/social/GoogleImpl.java:42: error: package com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin does not exist
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
                                             ^
/tmp/build6717517675623000166xxx/MainUI/src/main/java/com/codename1/social/GoogleImpl.java:43: error: package com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin does not exist
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInResult;
                                             ^
/tmp/build6717517675623000166xxx/MainUI/src/main/java/com/codename1/social/GoogleImpl.java:99: error: package Auth does not exist
        Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(client);
                                  ^
/tmp/build6717517675623000166xxx/MainUI/src/main/java/com/codename1/social/GoogleImpl.java:106: error: cannot find symbol
                    final GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
                          ^
  symbol: class GoogleSignInResult
/tmp/build6717517675623000166xxx/MainUI/src/main/java/com/codename1/social/GoogleImpl.java:106: error: package Auth does not exist
                    final GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
                                                          ^
/tmp/build6717517675623000166xxx/MainUI/src/main/java/com/codename1/social/GoogleImpl.java:110: error: cannot find symbol
                        GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
                        ^
  symbol: class GoogleSignInAccount
/tmp/build6717517675623000166xxx/MainUI/src/main/java/com/codename1/social/GoogleImpl.java:228: error: cannot find symbol
                GoogleSignInOptions gso;
                ^
  symbol:   class GoogleSignInOptions
  location: class GoogleImpl
/tmp/build6717517675623000166xxx/MainUI/src/main/java/com/codename1/social/GoogleImpl.java:232: error: package GoogleSignInOptions does not exist
                    gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                                                 ^
/tmp/build6717517675623000166xxx/MainUI/src/main/java/com/codename1/social/GoogleImpl.java:232: error: cannot find symbol
                    gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                                                          ^
  symbol:   variable GoogleSignInOptions
  location: class GoogleImpl
/tmp/build6717517675623000166xxx/MainUI/src/main/java/com/codename1/social/GoogleImpl.java:241: error: package GoogleSignInOptions does not exist
                    gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN).build();
                                                 ^
/tmp/build6717517675623000166xxx/MainUI/src/main/java/com/codename1/social/GoogleImpl.java:241: error: cannot find symbol
                    gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN).build();
                                                          ^
  symbol:   variable GoogleSignInOptions
  location: class GoogleImpl
/tmp/build6717517675623000166xxx/MainUI/src/main/java/com/codename1/social/GoogleImpl.java:246: error: cannot find symbol
                        .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                                ^
  symbol:   variable Auth
  location: class GoogleImpl
/tmp/build6717517675623000166xxx/MainUI/src/main/java/com/codename1/social/GoogleImpl.java:260: error: cannot find symbol
                    mGoogleApiClient.connect(GoogleApiClient.SIGN_IN_MODE_OPTIONAL);
                                                            ^
  symbol:   variable SIGN_IN_MODE_OPTIONAL
  location: interface GoogleApiClient
/tmp/build6717517675623000166xxx/MainUI/src/main/java/com/codename1/social/GoogleImpl.java:275: error: package Auth does not exist
                Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(client).setResultCallback(
```

I can also run it in debugger.

I need to use GoogleLogin, but I have no idea what caused this error.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same issue and i fixed it by remove android.includeGPlayServices build hint

Comment: Thanks. After removing the the build hint I can build. However the function doesn't work and it returns DEVELOPER_ERROR now...Thanks anyway

Comment: Just the problem of wrong web client ID. It works now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As Google effectively deprecated Google+ login we had to redo the whole `signin with Google` process. This is explained in the developer guide section about signing in with Google which is now rewritten and actually much simpler.

Just to be clear, we didn't have a choice... Google+ stopped working as Google discontinued support for it.

We discussed some of these changed in this [blog post](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/factional-padding-margin-rounded-border-ripple-caps-google-connect.html).

Comment: I have already done "Download the google-services.json file into your project’s native/android directory" but still the same error in build engine

Comment: Did you remove the old build hints?

Comment: Yes, no gplus build hints anymore. Do I need to remove/change codename1.arg.android.targetSDKVersion=23 ?

Comment: I would suggest removing anything that looks suspect and doing a refresh libs to install back anything required by a cn1lib. Also which cn1libs do you use? Just saw you used the outdated gplayservices that's a great find!